# Having performance issues with queries in MySQL when having one large table containing more than 8 million rows

Tags: mysql

I have one table in MySQL database that is containing various logs. Log table has more than 8 million rows. This table is on it's own and it's not in a relationship with any other tables.

Now when I execute queries on this or any other table, the queries are really slow (more than 20 seconds), and these are simple select and limit queries.

Then I started to delete rows from this logs table. Once the row count fell bellow 7.5M everything started working normally. The same queries were quick again (under a second). I deleted most of the rows and now have 500K rows left.

Also while the table contained more than 8M rows deletion of 10K rows took more than 60 seconds. Once the row count fell under 7.5M rows the delete queries became faster and were now able to delete 100K rows in 20 seconds.

My question is what am I doing wrong. Am I missing something since I know that MySQL should handle 8M rows normally. Are there any limitations on row count or on table size?

The MySQL database (MySQL 5.7.23) is deployed to a Linux machine with 160GB of disk space and 8GB of RAM. The disk has at least 120GB free. Also regarding other tables in the database, some have 300 rows and some have between 200K and 1M rows. The DB dump originally had 6.7GB and now after deleting now has 2.9GB.

If someone can help me with this I would appreciate it. Thanks!

EDIT:

The queries that I ran and were slow:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from logs_table;
SELECT COUNT(id) from logs_table;
SELECT * FROM logs_table LIMIT 1000;
SELECT * FROM logs_table LIMIT 1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM any_other_table;
SELECT * FROM any_other_table;
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the log table:

```
CREATE TABLE `channel_account_log` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  `channel_account_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL, 
  `request_data` longtext, 
  `request_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
  `requesturl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `response_data` longtext, 
  `response_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
  `responseurl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `status` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  `status_message` longtext, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
  KEY `FK_7lv26awkgdej6du76hq1111i` (`channel_account_id`), 
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7lv26awkgdej6du76hq1111i` FOREIGN KEY (`channel_account_id`) REFERENCES `channel_account` (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 25641307 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
```

And here is the explain result:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(id) from channel_account_log;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | channel_account_log | NULL | index | NULL | FK_7lv26awkgdej6du76hq1111i | 8 | NULL | 12838176 | 100.00 | Using index |

Edit 3

Here is table status result:

| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time | Update_time | Check_time | Collation | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| channel_account_log | InnoDB | 10 | Dynamic | 12838176 | 596 | 7657750528 | 0 | 178110464 | 7340032 | 25641307 | 2023-08-11 09:19:08 | 2023-08-11 09:27:31 | NULL | utf8_general_ci |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Here is show index result:

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| channel_account_log | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 12837914 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| channel_account_log | 1 | FK_7lv26awkgdej6du76hq1111i | 1 | channel_account_id | A | 8670 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |

Comment: As you haven't shared the query you are using, it's impossible to provide help. I would assume that this is a problem of missing or misconfigured indexes

Comment: and there are updates for mysql 5.7 that you should install

Comment: *when I execute queries .. the queries are really slow* See EXPLAIN, create needed indices. *deletion of 10K rows took more than 60 seconds* Think about table partitioning. Partition pruning allows to process only those partitions which contains the rows to be processed.

Comment: *`SELECT COUNT(*) from logs_table;`* Count any non-NULL indexed column instead. *`SELECT * FROM logs_table LIMIT 1000;`* What's the reason for to select 1000 random rows?

Comment: Yes I know there are updates but I want to know why this is happening

Comment: Please post the schema and `explain` output.

Comment: If "SELECT * FROM logs_table LIMIT 1;" is slow, something in your system (or your description) is broken. If your table is/was around 3gb and you have only 8gb of ram, it may just be a caching issue, e.g 7.5M rows fit in it, while 8M don't, or something. Reading 3GB from disk can indeed take (more than) 20 seconds, which you may have to do if you don't have indexes (which you didn't tell us, so please tell us, preferably with a `show create table logs_table`). Also maybe check your [buffer pool settings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/27328) and memory usage.

Comment: @Solarflare yeah I see what you mean. It makes sense that it couldn't fit more than 7.5M. While the performance was slow the RAM was at 30% - 50% and CPU 4 cores at 40% each. Well the table has an ID and it is an index which makes sense. There are multiple string rows, and they are NOT indexed. The thing that has me confused is why other queries on other tables (as simple as SELECT FROM table WHERE id = 123) were slow.

Comment: @edo You will need to edit your question and: 1. Provide the result of `show create table logs_table;`, 2. Narrow down the problem-space by choosing a single query that was slow and most bothersome, rather than a list of queries, 3. Provide the results of the `explain` for that query. Then we will be able to provide you more meaningful help.

Comment: @LajosArpad I added table CRATE and query EXPLAIN

Comment: So, you are searching for the count of primary key (which means it's indexed) and that takes 20 seconds, right?

Comment: Yes. Actually it took more than 40 seconds. When I selected COUNT(*) it actually timed out and never completed after more than 100 seconds. These things only happend when row count was more than 8M. After we deleted and went under 8M rows the speed came back to normal. Now count of primary keys takes about 0.5 seconds with 500K rows

Comment: Very interesting. I do not know what the exact cause might have been. But you could archive old records if you are interested only in newer records. Also, you could periodically load the result of your frequent queries and cache the results so they will be ready for use instantly when they are needed instead of waiting for them at each call.

Comment: @LajosArpad yep I'll definitely do that. This must then be some misconfiguration issue. Anyways thanks for your time and input!

Comment: Happy to help. I do not know an exact solution, so I will not write an answer, but I think the approach I described should lead you to a solution.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of  A) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "channel_account_log";  and B) SHOW INDEX FROM channel_account_log; for analysis, please.  Explain posted did not use the PRIMARY key when run.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I updated with table status and show index

Comment: I co not see a reason why your count query did not use the PRIMARY key that would take  less time to complete.  Please run the EXPLAIN SELECT .... again and post the results.  SHOW INDEX FROM tablename causes 'rebuild' of the indexes.  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck EXPLAIN result remained the same

Comment: Please consider posting the results from the EXPLAIN.  Thank you.

Comment: @WilsonHauck it is identical to the one I already added to the question that's why I didn't add it. literary the same.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SELECT @@version;  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck 5.7.29-log

Comment: Please try this and post TEXT results when time permits - EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(id) from channel_account_log FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY);  and share the appx. time to completion, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck here is the result of explain <<<1, SIMPLE, channel_account_log, , index, , PRIMARY, 8, , 9109435, 100.00, Using index>>>. The time for explain was 0s (instantly). Regular count query taking around 1.1 seconds

Comment: By using FORCE INDEX (primary) you avoided reading ~ 3,700,000 of the index rows.  This old version of MySQL apparently does not always choose the best index for the COUNT(*) task.  View profile, please for additional assistance.

Comment: Oh ok I see that. I know that updating to the latest version and cleaning up and archiving old/unnecessary rows is the way to go. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @Akina - The undo log is the slow part of deleting; partitioning does not help with that.  On the other hand, deleting a whole partition is fast.